# Reload page if Database changes

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, html

1. I can't set a javascript timer to reload the page every X seconds. It must be a perfect loop with no wait times.
2. I can't use AJAX. When the database changes a full screen video must be played, and there's no way I can load an "auto-fullscreen" HTML5 video from AJAX method through someotherfile.php

I spent 6 hours today trying to find a way to do this. Apparently I can't put PHP in a loop to 'listen' by doing sql queries every now and on. Weak language I guess.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I can't even reload the page by using AJAX through another php file. It just won't work, so let's forget about AJAX.

Comment: _Weak language I guess._ No. You're just asking a car to do the job a train or vice versa. You're looking for a real-time application or a long polling application that keeps the connection active through sockets or something like that, hence you need something that serves **both** the client and the server, which is not the purpose of php itself. In a nutsell, the only way you have through php and javascript is to perform ajax requests (perhaps simulating a long polling request) and get a result, else move on with something else, like nodejs or similars.

Comment: No. It has nothing to do with client and server. A loop is a loop, you can't make a loop independent in PHP, therefore the language is weak.

Comment: An indipendent loop in php means freezing the server (the current script), you are just using the wrong language, as I said above, there are languages and libraries that does it beautifully, but none of them is a server-side language. If you're here to keep telling that php is a weak language feel free to do it, meanwhile, I recommend you to check this: https://nodejs.org/ . Or just check this: https://github.com/panique/php-long-polling But it won't serve you **as well as applications that are developed for such a scope**.

Comment: I respect your opinion as long as it makes sense. Saying that PHP is a weak language because it doesn't do exactly what you want to do for that very specific case is simply not fair, because if you would've changed your logic you could've done that through php aswell. My goal here is to help users in the best way I can, that's why I've suggested you either nodejs or a javascript long polling: the other solutions are either not well supported or just not close to what you apparently want. That said, once again, **the closest you can get with php is long polling**, period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing in common with PHP weaknesses it's about server side and client side.

Answering your question. You should try using HTML5 server sent events check these links it should clarify you how to do it. There are examples given:

- http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

BTW you don't need reload page with JavaScript just simple meta referesh does this.

> Note: using EventSource is not supported by all browsers.

Comment: How do I insert meta refresh from the other PHP file and make my actual page reload whenever I do a query to the database?

Comment: Set header `header( "refresh:5;url=wherever.php" );` Where 5 is refresh interval with seconds